# What causes Dell XPS 13 ProjectSputnik to wake up randomly after suspend and how to fix it?

Tags: dell, power-management, suspend, xps

When I close the lid of my XPS13 the system goes to sleep regularly. Sometimes it stays asleep but some other times it wakes up consuming battery. I can't find the reason why this is happening. Here are the recent logs:

from pm-suspend.log

```
Thu Jun 20 08:59:47 PDT 2013: performing suspend
Thu Jun 20 11:00:18 PDT 2013: Awake.
Thu Jun 20 11:00:18 PDT 2013: Running hooks for resume
```

from syslog at the same time:

```
Jun 20 08:59:47 sputacchio kernel: [28423.044067] psmouse serio1: Trackpad at is
a0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Jun 20 08:59:47 sputacchio kernel: [28423.045743] psmouse serio1: Trackpad at is
a0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
Jun 20 11:00:18 sputacchio acpid: client 1669[0:0] has disconnected
Jun 20 11:00:18 sputacchio kernel: [28423.074982] psmouse serio1: Trackpad at is
a0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
```

Running stock kernel

```
# uname -a
Linux sputacchio 3.8.0-25-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 20:47:07 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I disabled Smart Connect in the BIOS but the laptop resumed last night without a reason (lid closed, sitting on the desk)

```
 Wed Jun 26 00:12:46 CEST 2013: performing suspend
 Wed Jun 26 01:53:10 CEST 2013: Awake.
 Wed Jun 26 01:53:10 CEST 2013: Running hooks for resume
```

Strangely there is no sign of activity on syslog around that time, so I'm assuming whatever wakes the system up is not the kernel. I have also disabled Intel Smart Start technology... Any other clues on things to disable?

Comment: The trigger to wake your machine is not controlled by Ubuntu. This is really the hardware changing from the ACPI power states. Maybe Dell has some software in Windows that handles these automatic events which then make it sleep again and a normal user will never notice this... (just guessing). I'm just saying that this is very very likely not related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This Launchpad bug looks like it might be the same issue you're experiencing:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell-sputnik/+bug/1161962

I suggest that you add a post to that bug describing your symptoms, and in particular the message "acpid: client 1669[0.0] has disconnected".

The Trackpad lost sync / resynced messages are normal side-effects of the suspend/resume process (they occur around every suspend/resume on the XPS 13) but the acpid message is not common, and might relate to your wakeup problem.

Comment: I would have never guessed that this was even a feature... how dumb can this be? http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2401223,00.asp Hopefully disabling it will make the issue go away.